# how to style html input file type using CSS

Tags: css

How do I remove the text-field like part of the input type=file and only keep the browse button using CSS??

Comment: This is a really nasty one that i'd like to know the best approach myself. I've tried several different ways, but is really difficult because different browsers handle it differently.

Comment: It's not exactly styling but i found out a work-around. I created another simple button #btn, and `$('#btn').Click(function(){$('#inputfield).click()});`  And I hide the #inputfield under some layer providing z-index with a minus value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we change <input type="file"> style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825509/can-we-change-input-type-file-style)

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky, but based on this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

I was able to accomplish what you're asking..