# How can you style an HTML file upload input element using jquery UI?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, file-upload, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we change <input type=“file”> style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825509/can-we-change-input-type-file-style)

JQuery UI does not *appear* to have any facility for styling file upload elements. Is there any way to syle file upload elements using jquery UI?