# How to vertically align filename on file input in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, file-upload

We have a file input on our site which isn't quite as high as in the demo (see below; I've exaggerated it to show the issue better) but we cannot get the filename to centre vertically - only the button centres vertically. This would not normally be an issue as we usually stick with the default style, but in this case the client wants a border on this input so that the right border lines up with some right-aligned buttons below it. The height, in our case, is 23px (same for line-height).

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/UK72P/ for a demo. To my knowledge this only happens in Chrome & possibly IE9 / 8 (will confirm shortly). The code in the jsfiddle is:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file">​
```

**CSS**

```
input {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

​

Is there some property I don't know about or is this just not possible?

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: You can't do anything with input type file, check out this link-- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825509/can-we-change-input-type-file-style)

Answer (score 13):

```
input[type="file"] {
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

This worked for me, Chrome 29.0.1547.57

Comment: Awesome! But even better: `line-height: 1ex;`, so it works even when the text size gets changed.

Comment: is there a variasion for firefox?

Answer (score 3):

The other solution works simply because the line-height is sufficiently small, so it'd make more sense to use a line-height of 0.

This will still have a non-zero height, it just removes "padding" -- for me margin and padding on file input was `0` by default.

```
input[type="file"] {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can align vertically input file field using input file button:

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome Hack

```
input{-bracket-:hack[;line-height:50px;];}
```

But it didn't fullfill our requirement. So for this purpose i make this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/hTezL/3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems like a bug in Chrome as it moves the button to the bottom of the line-height but won't move the generated text for anything. The solution is to set your height using margin and use an enclosing div if you want a border.

#### HTML

```
<div class="file-border">
  <input type=file>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.file-border {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

input {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Implemented in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4C6q/1/)